# Ag-grid hidden columns - Angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to add a message when I hide a column by `ToolPanel` or by `columnsMenu`.

How can I know which column is hidden?

I know which columns are hidden only when I load the grid by `gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState()` but I don't know what the method or event is to know in realtime which column I have hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [onColumnVisible](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0) event that you can listen to. If I'm reading the event hierarchy correct at the bottom, then you will be given the column or columns that were affected and whether or not they were hidden.

```
this.gridOptions.onColumnVisible = function (event) {
    if (event.visible) {
        console.log(event.column.colId + ' was made visible');
    } else {
        console.log(event.column.colId  + ' was hidden')
    }
}
```